# Does Eclipse Neon.1 support Play Framework?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, playframework-2.0, eclipse-neon

I am trying to learn the Play Framework and use Eclispe as my IDE.

I want to use Eclipse Neon.1 as my IDE, however I cannot find any instructions on how (or what) to install to enable developmenty of Play applications.

Is it possible and I am not looking in the right place?

Or am I stuck using Eclipse Lunar based Scala IDE?

Or do I have to purchase IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eclipse Neon in combination with the Play Framework, but you need to setup [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse).

As the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE#Setup-sbteclipse) states, this can be easily done by adding the following line to your `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

If you have only Java sources in your project, you also need to add the following lines to your `build.sbt` file:

```
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)
```

If you develop your project in Scala, then you need to install [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org). According to the [tool description](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/scala-ide) in the Eclipse marketplace, Scala IDE supports the following Eclipse versions:

> **Neon (4.6)**, Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8),
>   Previous to Juno (<=4.1), Oxygen (4.7)

If you want to have a complete integration of the Play Framework in IntelliJ IDEA, you may opt for the [Ultimate edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). Please note that you may be eligible for a free Ultimate license, if you are a [student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/). By the way, you do not necessarily need the Play plugin for IntelliJ. You can develop your Play apps in any editor or IDE and simply manage your projects via the command line.